# Question about the statement of the going-down theorem of Cohen-Seidenberg in Mumford

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes

In Mumford's red book the statement of the Going-Down Theorem (Chapter II Section 8) is as follows. 
Let $f: X \to Y$ be a finite morphism. Assume that $Y$ is an irreducible normal scheme. Assume that for all $x \in X$, no non-zero element of $O_{Y, f(x)}$ is a $0$-divisor in $O_{X,x}^{*}$. Then for every pair of points $x_1 \in X$, $y_0 \in Y$ such that 
$f(x_1) \in \overline{\{ y_0 \}}$, 
there is a point 
$x_0 \in f^{-1}(y_0)$ 
such that 
$x_1 \in \overline{ \{ x_0 \} }$.

By "no non-zero element of $O_{Y, f(x)}$ is a $0$-divisor in $O_{X,x}^{*}$", does this mean that it is ok if a non-zero element of $O_{Y, f(x)}$ gets mapped to $0$ in $O_{X,x}$? or does it mean every non-zero element of $O_{Y, f(x)}$ gets mapped to a non-zero element which is not a $0$-divisor in $O_{X,x}^*$? Thank you.

PS Instead of editing this question, I decided to ask separately [On an application of the going-down theorem of Cohen-Seidenberg in Mumford](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355694/on-an-application-of-the-going-down-theorem-of-cohen-seidenberg-in-mumford), which was the reason why I was trying to understand the statement in the first place.

Comment: To me, a "zero divisor" in a ring $R$ is an element $a$ such that multiplication by $a$ in $R$ is not injective. This includes $0$ if $R$ is not the zero ring.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly That is what I first thought as well, but then he does put the $*$, as in a $0$-divisor in $O_{X,x}^{*}$... Do you think that changes the meaning?

Comment: $R^*$ usually denotes non zero elements in a ring $R$..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Right, so I was wondering because he writes a $0$-divisor in $R^{*}$, is he excluding the zero element?

Comment: If you exclude 0 as you say, the result is obviously false: take  $X=\{x\}$ (a closed point of $Y$), $f$ the inclusion, and $y_0\neq x$.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly I don't quite follows what you mean. To apply the result one needs to specify a pair of points $x_1 \in X$ and $y_0 \in Y$ such that $f(x_1) \in \overline{\{ y_0 \}}$. But with your example one can not get such a pair to begin with?

Comment: Yes, of course: $x_1=x$, $y_0$=any generization of $x$ in $Y$, assuming of course $Y\neq\{x\}$.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly I see your point now thank you. And if I understand you correctly, then for example you are considering the morphism $f: \operatorname{Spec} \kappa(x) \to Y$, where the unique point is mapped to $x$ and $\kappa(x)$ is the residue field of $x$. In this case the map of the stalks is $O_{Y, x} \to O_{Y, x}/\mathfrak{m}_x \hookrightarrow \kappa(x)$. This means some of the non-zero elements of $O_{Y,x}$ gets mapped to $0$, so by the $0$-divisor he is probably including $0$.. Is there an easy example where this morphism is finite?

Comment: It is always finite if $x$ is a closed point.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: That mark * is not a star on the ring but an asterisk referring the reader to a footnote at the bottom of the page.  This the one instance where the Springer edition is clearer than the original.

Comment: @roysmith O right...