# On an application of the going-down theorem of Cohen-Seidenberg in Mumford

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes

There is a following result in Mumford's red book of schemes (Chapter II Section 8). Here $R$ is a valuation ring with algebraically closed fraction field $k$.

Let $Z \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ be an irreducible closed subset of dimension $r$ and let $\mathcal{Z} = \overline{ \{ i(Z)\} }$, where $i: \mathbb{P}^n_k \to \mathbb{P}^n_R$. Thee exist $(r+1)$ linear forms defined by $\ell_0 = ... = \ell_r = 0$, which we denote by $\mathcal{L}$, is disjoint from $\mathcal{Z}$. Let $\tau$ be the projection $\mathbb{P}^n_R \backslash \mathcal{L} \to \mathbb{P}^r_R$. Then giving any structure of closed subscheme, $\tau: \mathcal{Z} \to \mathbb{P}^r_R$ is a finite surjective morphism.

Then later on he applies the Going-Down theorem ([Question about the statement of the going-down theorem of Cohen-Seidenberg in Mumford](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355627/question-about-the-statement-of-the-going-down-theorem-of-cohen-seidenberg-in-mu?noredirect=1#comment892574_355627)) to this morphism $\tau: \mathcal{Z} \to \mathbb{P}^r_R$. One of the conditions is that no non-zero element of $O_{\mathbb{P}_R^r, \tau(x)}$  is a $0$-divisor in $O_{\mathcal{Z},x}$. I have been trying to prove that this condition is satisfied, and I would greatly appreciate any explanation of this. Thank you.

Below is my attempt:
By restricting to affine open $D(\ell_j)$, where $\ell_j \neq 0$, without loss of generality it suffices to consider
$$
\operatorname{Spec}{R[\frac{X_0}{\ell_0}, \ldots, \frac{X_n}{\ell_0}]/I} \to
\operatorname{Spec}{ R[\frac{X_0}{\ell_0}, \ldots, \frac{X_n}{\ell_0}]} \to
\operatorname{Spec}{R[\frac{Y_1}{Y_0}, \ldots, \frac{Y_r}{Y_0}]}, 
$$
where $D(\ell_0) \cap \mathcal{Z} = \operatorname{Spec}{ R[\frac{X_0}{\ell_0}, \ldots, \frac{X_n}{\ell_0}]/I}$. 
Thus it suffices to consider the ring homomoprhisms
$$
\tau^{\#}: R[\frac{Y_1}{Y_0}, \ldots, \frac{Y_r}{Y_0}] \to R[\frac{X_0}{\ell_0}, \ldots, \frac{X_n}{\ell_0}] \to R[\frac{X_0}{\ell_0}, \ldots, \frac{X_n}{\ell_0}]/I, 
$$
where the first map is defined by 
$$
\frac{Y_j}{Y_0} \mapsto \frac{\ell_j}{\ell_0}. 
$$

Let $Q$ be a prime ideal of $R[\frac{X_0}{\ell_0}, \ldots, \frac{X_n}{\ell_0}]/I$ and $Q' = (\tau^{\#})^{-1}(Q)$.
Then we consider the map of stalks by looking at the following commutative diagram 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
R[\frac{Y_1}{Y_0}, \ldots, \frac{Y_r}{Y_0}] @>>> R[\frac{X_0}{\ell_0}, \ldots, \frac{X_n}{\ell_0}]/I \\
@VVV @VVV\\
R[\frac{Y_1}{Y_0}, \ldots, \frac{Y_r}{Y_0}]_{Q'} @>>> (R[\frac{X_0}{\ell_0}, \ldots, \frac{X_n}{\ell_0}]/I)_{Q}.
\end{CD}
But then it seems possible that 
for some $j$, $Y_j/Y_0 \mapsto \ell_j/\ell_0$ and this $\ell_j/\ell_0$ may be in $I$. And in this case we don't have that no non-zero element of $O_{\mathbb{P}_R^r, \tau(x)}$  is a $0$-divisor in $O_{\mathcal{Z},x}$...

Comment: Mumford's footnote to the statement of Going Down, (p.252, original redbook), says the condition needed is that all associated points of OsubZ lie over the generic point of the target.  Does that help, if say Z is chosen reduced as well as irreducible?

Comment: I am a novice on this sort of thing, but my reading, say of Ravi's course notes, suggests that an irreducible reduced variety has only one associated point, its generic point. Thus a surjection of varieties would seem to always satisfy the condition in Mumford's footnote.  The connection between the two versions of the condition seems to be that a zero divisor is exactly a section that vanishes at an associated point.  Does this do it?  As to your computation, algebra is my weak point, but wouldn't the concern raised in your next to last sentence imply that tau is not surjective?

Comment: @roysmith I think it's clear now. Thank you!

Comment: You are quite welcome.  I am myself currently reading the redbook, and found chap. II.8 particularly challenging.  I am up to III.1 now and looking forward to the payoff geometry in sections ≥ III.3 !